# Blank Map When download app Android Market

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem about google map.

I did an app about include google maps.When i run the app with
Eclipse ,map is seeming everything is ok.

I signed the app and upload Android Market. When i dowload this app
for check i see the map blank.

I changed map key but it doesnt work?

Anybody know about that?

Comment: You must first create a new key (not the one in your debug.keystore) using keytool, then use that to sign your app, then submit that key to Google to get a new API key. Did you do all that?

Comment: Hi Nick. i didnt know that between debug.keystore and signed keystore.I was thinking they are same but if you publish an app android market you must use signed keystore when you get map key.That is it.Thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you changed the key of the google map component before sign? you must have a key for debug and another for published application.